# ECS get access to ECR in separate account

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I'm using AWS/Terraform with ECS and I have a set up where I have multiple AWS accounts that all need access to Docker images contained in ECR in separate AWS account.

In the separate AWS account (the one with the Docker images in ECR) I have created a user with an Access Key (ID & secret).

In my other AWS accounts I have ECS Task Definitions where I can specify the location of the Docker image, however, when I run the task it requires access to the other account to be able to pull the image.

How can I specify in my Terraform ECS task definition that to pull the Docker image from the other account that it needs to authenticate with the Access Key of the user in that other account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In the separate AWS account (the one with the Docker images in ECR) I have created a user with an Access Key (ID & secret).

The cross account access to the ECR repo should be set using [repository policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policies.html), not IAM user. Example of such a policy is [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secondary-account-access-ecr/).

In terraform, you set the ECR policy using [aws_ecr_repository_policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64256281/ecs-get-access-to-ecr-in-separate-account). In addition, your `aws_ecs_task_definition` will need to specify [task_role_arn](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition#task_role_arn) with permissions to access the ECR repo in the other account.

Comment: how can we give more granular access instead of just giving access to root? if I have to add task_role_arn into ecr permissions policy how can we do it with terraform? the issue is, aws_iam_policy_attachment only accepts users, groups and roles as input and not ecr pository name

Comment: @karthikeayan You can specify a IAM user or role, if you don't want to use root. Regarding terraform, its better to make question about it and explain what do you want to do.

Comment: sure here you go, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66382655/how-to-append-policy-to-aws-ecr-permissions