# How to append policy to AWS ECR Permissions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

This is cross account setup. ECR is on Account 1 and Apps on ECS will be deployed into Account 2.

I have a ECS/Fargate module, when I call this module, it creates below resources for example,

1. ECS Service
2. Cloudwatch Log Group
3. IAM Roles for ECS Task Role and Task Execution Role
4. Load balancer target group
5. Load balancer listener rule

Purpose of module is reusability, so when I have a new application, I just add the module snippet into the Terraform code, so that it can provision all the resources mentioned above once again.

Lets assume I have application A and application B.

Now, how can I add Task Execution Role of A and B into ECR Permissions?

When application B is getting provisioned I want to add the Task Execution Role of B into ECR Permissions policy without removing the Application A's Task Execution Role.

I couldn't find a way to just append one statement into ECR Permissions policy.

Comment: Can you do it the other way? Your Task Execution Role has permissions to access ECR, rather then updating exiting ECR resource-based policy to add new roles.

Comment: Thats possible but still risky, for example, when I allow root(everyone) on another account, anyone can create IAM user/role with ecr:* on the other account and get access to my ecr repo. Yes, only if they know account id and repo name.

Comment: So this is cross account? Its not clear from your question.

Comment: my bad, forgot to mention, yes this is cross account setup, updated question also